# Primefaces: Input Text / Overlay panel / Retain focus

Tags: jsf, primefaces, focus

We have a `p:inputText` element that should display an overlay panel for various options. (Its a global search, so you can tick categories to search in)

*Users usually click in the textbox, start typing and THEN look at the screen again*

The Problem is: As soon as the overlay panel is shown, the textbox looses its focus.

```
<p:inputText id="searchItem"></p:inputText>
<p:overlayPanel id="gsOverlay" for="searchItem" my="left top" 
 at="left bottom" dynamic="true" 
 onShow="resizeGSOverlay();">
```

So i tried to fix this, by immediately focusing back on the "search" `inputtext` using

```
<p:overlayPanel id="gsOverlay" for="searchItem" my="left top" 
 at="left bottom" dynamic="true" 
 onShow="PrimeFaces.focus('globalSearchForm:searchItem'); resizeGSOverlay();">
```

However, there is a split second, where the inputfield lost focus, leading to searches missing the first charater.

Can i display the overlay panel, without having the inputtext loosing its focus? (Each component inside the overlay panel will focus back after clicking, that's fast enough - just the initial focus-back is to slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the "holy grail":

Default for the `overlayPanel` is:

```
    PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.applyFocus = function(){
        this.jq.find(':not(:submit):not(:button):input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
    }
```

so, I just put the following javascript AFTER including the primefaces resources, which will then override the default implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.applyFocus = function() {
       if (this.id == "globalSearchForm:gsOverlay")
          return;
       else
          this.jq.find(':not(:submit):not(:button):input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
    }
</script>
```

So - No focus for any element within the overlay panel in question once it becomes visible. Works like a charm.

---

Update:
using the Proxy Pattern (http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Proxy_Pattern) seems a more reliable solution, as it avoids the need to duplicate the content of the original implementation, which might be different in one of the next Primefaces releases:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var proxied = PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.applyFocus;

        PrimeFaces.widget.OverlayPanel.prototype.applyFocus = function(){
            if (this.id == "globalSearchForm:gsOverlay")
                return;

            return proxied.apply(this, arguments); 
        };
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: The holy grail being the PF source… great… more people should do that.